# Futter Getx GetConnect Post Request Responding into 401 Error

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am trying developing a Flutter app using `Getx` state management. I am extending and implementing `GetConnect` and `GetxService` respectively in my APIClient calss. I am getting perfect result in `Postman` but getting `401` error while requesting from the app. The app is sending the `Authorization` Bearer token without issue.

Please, help me find out where it is going wrong and the solution.

I need to post form-data that's why I have created a `Header`

```
_mainHeaders = ({
      'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    });
```

I am sending a `FormData`  as body using Getx `GetConnect` class. The FormData body is:

```
FormData formData = FormData({
          'name': name,
          'email': email,
          'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
          'description': description
        });
```

Here is the post method:

```
Future<Response> postData(String uri, dynamic body) async {
    try {
      Response response = await post(uri, body, headers: _mainHeaders);
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      return Response(statusCode: 1, statusText: e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Till GetX `get: ^4.6.6` **FormData** is not supported though it is imported from **GetX**.

To solve that I used **`dio`** package to handle post-request for FormData.

And, if your dio http client class extends getx package then at the top make sure adding:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart' hide FormData;
```